# How to display posts of a particular category in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

I have a simple blog site and am trying to retrieve posts from a particular category. I have set the model as follows.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

    attr_accessible :author, :description, :title, :photo, :category_ids

    scope :breaking, lambda { |category_ids|
        joins(:categorizations).where('categorizations.category_id' => category_ids)
    }
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :category_id, :position, :post_id

    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :category
end
```

I wrote a scope in the post model called *breaking*, and I don't know how to render it in the view. And also what will the controller look like and is my scope breaking in order to retrieve the posts under a particular category?

Answer (score 1):

Change your scope declaration to:

```
scope :breaking, lambda { |category_ids|
    joins(:categorizations).where('categorizations.category_id = ?', category_ids)
}
```

or

```
scope :breaking, lambda { |category_ids|
    joins(:categorizations).where(categorizations: { category_id: category_ids })
}
```

Instead of using lambdas on scopes, I prefer class methods because, for me, they look more readable. Plus it's easier to add default values.

```
def self.breaking(category_ids)
    joins(:categorizations).where(categorizations: { category_id: category_ids })
end
```

Comment: and please what about the controller and view what will they look like thanks

Comment: unfortunately, i can't answer that here. you're going to have to go through a tutorial to do that or ask another question.